# giving input to a batch file from java

Tags: java, input, batch-file

I have a batch file which on opening displays options console to perform different actions. I want to call this batch file from my java code and also give input to different options input at different places in my code.
i tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start adress/sys.bat"); which displays the options as I mentioned earlier. Now I want to give input to the console from java itself to select an option. Is it possible? –

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: i tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start adress/sys.bat"); which displays the options as I mentioned earlier. Now I want to give input to the console from java itself to select an option. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can list crontab tasks for a specific user in Linux environment:

```
String cmd = "crontab -u someuser -l";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

Here, `crontab` is a system shell script that accespts options/arguments like -u, -l, and I hope that you can find analogy with your case.